# Hash location with offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some trouble with my navigation on an one page design. Below is my code. The code works fine on the homepage.

The fixed header will not overlap the section part and it works great. But when I am on a single page of the website, and click on a menu item that links to a section on the homepage like `<a href="index.html#video"></a>` the scroll animation will animate to that section, but then the fixed header is overlapping that section part, when you wait a second of 3 it will turn back to its right place.

I think the animation will execute 2 times, but I don't now if that is the issue. Also I was wondering how to code, when the user is refreshing the page it will turn back to the top of the browser window.

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/42/

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by intercepting the `onhashchange` event and adjusting the offset of the `window`:

```
(function($){
    if ( "onhashchange" in window ) {
        var hashHandler = function(){
            var hash = window.location.hash.substring( 1 );
            if ( !hash )
                return;

            var offset = 50;
            var sel = '[id="' + hash + '"], a[name="' + hash + '"]';
            var currentOffset = $( sel ).offset().top;

            $( window ).scrollTop( currentOffset + offset );
        };
        window.addEventListener("hashchange", hashHandler, false);
        window.addEventListener("load", hashHandler, false);
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the calculation. For me it worked after I changed the calculation to `currentOffset - offset` (changed the `+` to a `-`).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the complete handler of the animation. You do this:

```
window.location.hash = id;
```

This method moves the scroll to the object with the id 'id', but of course, this ignores the offset (the header's height) you use to calculate, that's why the fixed head overlapps your section.

I suggest you to use false ids, something like this:

```
window.location.hash = '!' + id;
```

And then, when you load the page...

```
gotoByScroll(windwo.location.hash.substr(2);
```

This way, there's no element with that id in the page, and there isn't  a second scroll.

Hope this works.

Comment: thank you, but also this isn't working for me. It will do the same. JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/27/

Comment: It works. There was a syntax error in the jsfiddle. I've updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/29/

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain exactly correct. Because the code basically works simply. This goes to the correct section, only when you are on video and the browser instance is refreshed, you will see the first header are incorrect, then called after 3 seconds. The latter is still the case.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I will try to explain. The code in my JSFiddle works. It goes to the right section and will correctly position it, so the fixed header is not override the section. Ok? But when I refreshed the page it doesn't position correctly. Now it's working with the update of @joelrobichaud only when I am on a external link and will go back, it will position incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting both `html` and `body` in your selector, the animation is done twice on browsers that support animating on both of these elements. In order to prevent this behavior, you need to stop animating once either animation is done. To do this, you can use the [stop method](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), like so :

```
$('html, body').stop(true, true).animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500, function () {
    window.location.hash = id;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/25/)

---

EDIT: Combining my answer and Oscar's answer, I get something that seems to work by adding bangs before the sharps in the urls.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/28/)

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. But unfortunately it works the same as before. First it goes to the position, like there is no fixed header, than after 3 seconds it goes back so the fixed header is right positioned.

Comment: Thank you, we're almost there. When I click on video, he goes to the appropriate section (video). If I refresh, it does not seem weird anymore. But when I am on another page and I click on the menu on video (`index.html#video`), the fixed header is not included.

Comment: It doesn't solved the problem. :( As I said before, when on single.html and click on the section video, the fixed header will override the video section. After 3 seconds it's going to the right place.

Comment: this work, just change `var id = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);` and  `var target = $("#"+id).offset().top - offset;` then when you link your page do it like this: `index.html#!video`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/40/)

Comment: @MamaWalter Not for me. :( if I past your code in mine, and go from `single.html` to `index.html#video` the header is overlap the section.

Answer (score 0):

Save the current scroll position first, then change hash, then apply saved scroll position, then apply animation.

```
var target = $(id).offset().top - offset,
    scrollmem = $('html, body').scrollTop();

window.location.hash = id;
$('html, body').scrollTop(scrollmem).animate({ scrollTop: target    }, 500, function () {
  // nothing here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/34/

if using plugin is not a problem with you, use jQuery ScrollTo plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Also, if you're already using `event.preventDefault()`, you don't need to use `return false;` to prevent default click behavior of '' tag

Comment: @Dab1121, I don't know why. I don't down vote your answer. Your code is also working. Only after clicked on a section link on the single page doesn't work the same.

Comment: there are some quirks on the code with regards to browser compatibility. I've used jQuery ScrollTo plugin for this and it works magic.

Comment: I've updated my solution to this: http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/38/ as Chrome does not compute scrollTop() properly.

Comment: I have past your code in mine, but when I am on the single page and click for example on video it will overlap first, after that it goes to the right position. Also I was wondering how I can fix it when the user is refreshing the page that it will go to the top of the browser? @Dan1121

Answer (score 0):

I've made another solution.

```
// The id of the section we want to go to.
var id = $(this).attr("href"),
    $id = $(id),
    dataID = id.substr(1);

// Our scroll target : the top position of the
// section that has the id referenced by our href.
var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;

    $id.attr('data-id',dataID).attr('id','');
    window.location.hash = id;
    $id.attr('id',dataID);

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target},500);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7PKAX/8/

What this does is it removes the "id" on the target element (passed to `data-id` attribute) before changing the hash to prevent the jump (as it's not found on the document), then add it back after the change.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need your ids to target your sections you could give them differents names than your hashtags (be sure hashtags doesn't exist in the page);

HTML:

```
<section id="section-portfolio">...</section>
```

JS:

```
var id = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);

var target = $("#section-"+id).offset().top - offset;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E773g/41/)